# Visual Studio 2015 - current ui culture in XAML designer

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015

I have installed english windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 with multiple language packages. I am developing multilanguage WPF application. It would be nice to see localized strings during design time and not only if I run application with set CurrentUICulture to tested language.

I noticed that if I change language in Visual Studio's Tools\International settings its culture is used for display language of menus (as intended) and even for resources used in XAML designer. This of course requires VS restart.

Following XAML code will display button with text "Cancel" (english version of resource string). It would be nice if there would be simple way to make change display text to "Stornieren" (german version) just by some simple switch in VS.

```
<Button Content="{x:Static mcp:WpfResources.CmdCancel}" Width="160" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" IsCancel="True"/>
```

Any idea?
Thanks